# Executing a jquery function stored as a variable name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm struggling with figuring out how to call/execute a function in jQuery. I've done quite a bit of searching and find what looks like it *should* be the answer, but it doesn't seem to work. I assume it is a scope issue since everything else seems to match examples I've found here, but I'm relatively new to jQuery and can't quite figure it out.

Basically, when the "bookmark" button is clicked, it uses ajax to create an entry in the database, and changes the format of the clicked button. This acts as expected. The trick is this requires someone to be logged in. The actual click of the button adds a #bookmarkme anchor to the url - if they aren't logged in (this is where things start getting tricky for me), the log in window pops up and they are prompted to sign up/log in, and the page reloads to set all the log in variables properly. This also works as expected. Where it breaks down is once the user logs in and the page reloads, I can't get the "bookmarkFunction" to run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var loggedin = <?php echo $loggedin; ?>;

 var headerButtonScript = function(){
  var bookmarkFunction = $("#bookmark").click(function(){
   var directoryName = "<?php echo $directoryName;?>";
   if(loggedin == 1 && $("#bookmark").hasClass("headerButton")){
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "../includes/bookmarkProcess.php",
     data: {directory: directoryName},
     success: function(data, status){
      if(data == "success"){
       $("#bookmark").switchClass("headerButton", "headerButtonDisabled", 1000, "easeInOutQuart");
       $("#bookmark").text("Bookmarked");
      }
     }
    });
   }
   else{
    $("#signInContent").toggleClass('hidden');
    $("#signInPopUp").toggleClass('hidden');
   }
  });
 };

 var headerButtonsAfterLoad = function(){
  var currentAddress = window.location.href;
  var hashPosition = currentAddress.indexOf("#");
  var targetLocation = currentAddress.substring(hashPosition+1);

  if(targetLocation == "bookmarkme"){
   if(loggedin==1){
    //CALL bookmarkFunction HERE;
    //I know I get to this location when expected, because placing an alert("message") gives me the pop up
   }
  }
 };

 $(document).ready(headerButtonScript);
 $(window).bind('load',"",headerButtonsAfterLoad);
</script>
```

Based on my research, I have tried the following lines (one line attempted each time rather than all at once, of course) in the excerpt to try to call the function, but no luck yet.

```
  if(targetLocation == "bookmarkme"){
   if(loggedin==1){
    //CALL bookmarkFunction HERE;
    bookmarkFunction();
    bookmarkFunction.run();
    bookmarkFunction.call();
    bookmarkFunction.apply();
   }
  }
```

Any help on locating my issue - scope, methods, or otherwise - is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know why you are making it so complex... `bookmarkFunction` is not a function... it is a jQuery object...

Comment: `bookmarkFunction.click()`

Comment: @epascarello - I need the script to take the same action it would when I click on the bookmark button (ID = bookmark) when the page reloads and has the anchor #bookmarkme OR when the ID is clicked. Triggering on a click is easy, but I can't get it to trigger on the reload if the anchor is there.

Comment: and `bookmarkFunction.click()` does just that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I need the script to take the same action it would when I click on the bookmark button (ID = bookmark) when the page reloads and has the anchor #bookmarkme"

This will do what you want^

```
$('#bookmarkme').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks, worked exactly as I wanted, with the slight modification of the ID to #bookmark - I just use anchor bookmarkme which doesn't refer to any element so that it doesn't automatically scroll anywhere. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

`$("#bookmark").click()`. should work.

Remember, calling a jQuery method on a jQuery object returns the original jQuery object. So if you say:

```
var bookmark=$('#bookmark')
```

Then bookmark is set to the jQuery object (which contains the element of id=bookmark as a property).

If you attach methods to the object like this:

```
var bookmark=$('#bookmark').click(function(){console.log('You clicked!')})
```

Then, yes, the element with id bookmark will now call this event when you click it, but the click method on a jquery object returns the original jquery object. That means bookmark will still be equal to `$("#bookmark")`, not the function in the `click` method.

So in conclusion, when you attach an event to a jquery object, like click or hover, it goes into the dom and attaches the event, and then returns the original jquery object. That way you can do things like:

```
var bookmark=$("#bookmark").click(function(){console.log("you clicked")}).mouseover(function(){console.log("you moused over")})
```

And you can keep attaching events forever and ever, and `bookmark` will always be equal to `$("#bookmark")`